# Можно ли распостранять свой api_id и api_hash?

Tags: api, telegram, telethon

Я разрабатываю кастомный клиент Telegram, и чтобы позволить пользователю в нём авторизоваться, мне нужно указать `api_id` и `api_hash`.

На сайте *my.telegram.org* указано: `"it is forbidden to pass this value to third parties"`. Получается, мне нужно требовать от конечного пользователя идти на сайт *my.telegram.org* и указывать свои значения?

Как тогда работают остальные клиенты? Что вообще можно сделать, имея чей-то `api_id` и `api_hash`?

Comment: >Что вообще можно сделать, имея чей-то api_id / api_hash: например использовать https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/signing-in.html или https://docs.pyrogram.org/intro/quickstart для взаимодействия с Telegram от имени пользователя

Comment: @Violet но взаимодействия с Telegram будут производиться не от имени владельца api_hash/api_id, а от имени юзера, который по ним залогинился

Comment: мой комментарий на конкретный подвопрос вашего вопроса